# Many to Many relationship with pivot table

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-4

Hi I am attempting to use tags in my application but I am not sure the best way to set up the database schema for this along with how I would access the data through eloquent.

my current structure:
I have a many to many relationship with a pivot table as follows.

tables:

```
apps
services
service_app
```

an app can have multiple services running on it and a service can be running on multiple apps.

I would like to somehow add tags to this structure but it would have to be on the pivot table.This is what I was thinking:

tables:

```
services
apps
service_app
tags
tag_service_app
```

I would like the tags to be more of a group this way I can tell which combination of app/service is in which "group".

this would create another many to many relationship using the original pivot table. Is this possible/is there a better way to do this? also how would this data be access through eloquent?

Comment: What exactly in your case does 'pattern' and 'pool' refer to? You *can* (kinda) do what you want, though you'd have to model the pivot table. But yeah, adding tags to each individual pivot relationship doesn't sound like something that'd make sense under normal circumstances, hence asking what pattern and pool specifically refer to. I think knowing that would really help people know the best way to go about this.

Comment: I have updated the names to be a little easier to understand.

Comment: also added an explanation of how I will use tags